# How do I loop through this C# IDictionary to get the keys and values for each IDictionary entry?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and have this `IDictionary`:

```
IDictionary<string, IList<string>> myVariable;
```

I tried this:

```
foreach(IList<Strintg> str in myVariable.Values){
    foreach(String subStr in str){
        Console.WriteLine(subStsr);
    }
}
```

This gives me the values well enough, but I want something that will give me the keys **and** values:

```
key01
    value01
    value02
    value03
    value04
    value05
    ...


key02
    value01
    value02
    value03
    value04
    value05
    ...


key03
    value01
    value02
    value03
    value04
    value05
    ...

...
```

How do I go about grabbing each `String` key for each `IDictionary` entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries can be looped with `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` or just use var for convenience.

```cs
foreach(var pair in myVariable)
{
  string key = pair.Key;
  List<string> val = pair.Value;
  // do your thing
}
```

Alternatively you could also iterate over the keys and use them to access the dictionary:

```cs
foreach(string key in myVariable.Keys)
{
  List<string> val = myVariable[key];
  // do your thing
}
```

Comment: The latter involves some unnecessary look up code. The former should be preferred